# tinyMCE: No longer displays content, toolbar replaced by 3 dots

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-5

This problem started today. All of a sudden, tinyMCE no longer shows the original textarea's content and instead of the toolbar, I see 3 dots:

[image: tinyMCE not showing content]

The content is actually there (as you can see by the text "139 WORDS" in the bottom right). If I click "Preview"(under File) the contents show up in the preview window. If I reload the page, sometimes the contents and the toolbar show up (about once in 15 reloads). I've tested this with FireFox, Chrome and Edge. All have the same problem.

If I inspect the page (with the browser's development tools), I see no errors.

This is how I include tinyMCE in my page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/<my API key>/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
```

So what's wrong here?

**========== EDIT ==========**

I found out what is *causing* this, not *why* it happens or how to *solve* it (or why the problem suddenly started today). My textarea is inside a container div which I move around in the DOM. This container div sometimes gets a new parent. As soon as it does, the contents disappear and the 3 dots appear.

**========== EDIT 2 ==========**

I realized I might need to clarify my above edit. The reason why the editor sometimes gets a new parent is because I want to "disable" usage of it. I use a simple trick for this. Just before the editor's container div, I have another div:

```
<div id="disable_edit" style="position:relative;cursor:not-allowed">
  <div id="wall" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.65; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
<div id="editor">
  <textarea id="description"></textare>
</div>
```

When I want to "disable" editing, I simply move the *editor* div (through Javascript) inside the *disable_edit* div:

```
<div id="disable_edit" style="cursor:not-allowed">
  <div id="editor">
    <textarea id="description"></textare>
  </div>
  <div id="wall" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.65; z-index: 1;"></div>
</div>
```

This always worked perfectly. So not sure why all of a sudden, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

you may have a display:none for iframe somewhere in your codes .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).